# Search Filter for one level down in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite

Basically, what I need to do is get at the Billing Transactions:Internal Id field in a script for searching.

I have a saved Transaction search, where type = Purchase Order. I need to get the PO internalid AND the Billing Transaction: Internal Id. The saved search is fine.

Because in script the nlapiSearchRecord can only get one record, and I have over 9,000 rows, I am doing a loop where I am adding a filter of internalid >= the last internalId of the previous execution (1,000 rows). However, I need the filter for this search to be on the Billing Transaction:Internal Id NOT the PO Internal ID.

What "field" can I use in the nlobjSearchFilter creation to get the Billing Transaction:Internal Id?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [NetSuite Records Browser](https://system.sandbox.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2014_1/script/record/purchaseorder.html), if you check the *Search Filters* section for Purchase Orders, there is a filter there called `billingtransaction` that you can use. There is also a Search Column of the same name, so you can also retrieve that in your results.

Another option, if you have a saved search and are comfortable with your script executing saved searches, you can simply pass the search ID to `nlapiSearchRecord` or `nlapiCreateSearch` to execute the saved search or modify it then execute it, respectively. We typically avoid doing this in our code because any Administrator can modify a Saved Search, even Private ones, but it is an option nonetheless.